# python syntax error when accessing variable from within loop

Tags: python, loops, syntax

```
for foldername in os.listdir(mainpath):
 x = 0
 if foldername[-4:] != ".rar":
  path = mainpath + "\\" + foldername
  for i in os.listdir(path):
   if i[-4:] == '.jpg' or i[-5:] == '.jpeg':
    #Do something with with image found
    x += 1


 if x > 0:
  #images found
```

Python keeps giving me a syntax error at  x += 1

Theres nothing wrong with syntax, I just increment variable each time I find an image and reset it x = 0 when the main loop moves to a new folder

Comment: Can you share a full traceback, and also what's your python version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably missing a closing parenthesis on the line before the `x += 1`, in the section you omitted:

```
#Do something with with image found
```

Check the last line of `do something` and make sure that your parenthesis, brackets and curly braces are all balanced.

Comment: Oops yea I was missing a bracket indeed, what a silly mistake ^^